# how to run multiple command inside other terminal using batch file

Tags: batch-file, cmd

i am using nvs, and there is a nvs command line using which i can change my node version.
currently i am using .bat file from Desktop and then go to nvs terminal

```
cd C:\nvs
start "C:\nvs\nvs.cmd"
```

this opens the terminal, and then i need to type more commands inside nvs terminal like

```
nvs use node/10.16.3/x64
cd ../code/api
node -v
code .
```

i need to automate this and all the executables to be part of the .bat file.
i tried using /c or /k to concatenate the commands. but the terminal closes before executing anything. how to run these commands as a part of batch file together.

Comment: `start "C:\nvs\nvs.cmd"` should have been `start "" "C:\nvs\nvs.cmd"` but must instead be `call "C:\nvs\nvs.cmd"`.

Comment: but how to run the other consecutive commands

Comment: That's going to require `nvs` to be able to have some sort of scripting capability of its own

Comment: There is no batch file needed at all. Browse in Windows File Explorer to `C:\Windows\Systm32\cmd.exe`, right click on this file, click in context menu __Send to__ on __Desktop (create shortcut)__. Minimize or close Windows File Explorer. There is on your desktop a shortcut file with name `cmd.exe` (and not visible file extension `.lnk`). Right click on this file and use __Rename__ to change the file name to `Start NVS` or whatever you like. Then right click once again on the renamed shortcut file and click in context menu on the last item __Properties__.

Comment: There is the property __Target__ which needs to be extended by appending a space and `/D /S /K "C:\nvs\nvs.cmd & nvs use node/10.16.3/x64 & cd ..\code\api & node -v & code ."`. The property __Start in__ must be configured with `C:\nvs`. I recommend to change also the property __Comment__ to whatever you like and perhaps you click also on button __Change Icon__ to use a different icon for this shortcut. You can also modify other properties of the shortcut like number of rows and columns, other font, font and background color, etc. Finally click on button __OK__.

Comment: The shortcut is now ready for usage to run `cmd.exe` which runs first `C:\nvs\nvs.cmd`, next unconditionally `nvs use node/10.16.3/x64` (file extension appended to `nvs` would be better), then `cd ..\code\api` (the directory separator on Windows is ``\`` and not `/` as on Linux/Mac) and next `node -v` (file extension appended to `node` would be better) and last `code .` (file extension appended to `code` would be again better) and finally `cmd.exe` keeps running. Please note that I don't know anything about `nvs`. So I don't know what `C:\nvs\nvs.cmd` and the other executed files do.